# Adding flags in CodeBlocks compiler

Tags: c, codeblocks, flags

I'm writting a program with POSIX semaphore usage in CodeBlocks. So it can't compile even a such code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int main()
{
    sem_t a;
    sem_init(&a, 0, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

But using terminal and flag `-lpthread`, everything works.

> gcc main.c -lpthread

So, how can I add this flag to compiler?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, i would be very nice, if you could copy-paste my code and compile it.

Comment: It's a linker flag. Are there linker options?

Comment: @koshachok What? I hope that comment is supposed to be a joke.

Comment: See this  http://askubuntu.com/a/568092/444760

Comment: No, no, no. I was about to give an Answer to the Question. The duplicated link has nothing to do whit this Question. There is About compiler FLAGS and not about Linker FLAGs. Please reopen the Question

Comment: I posted there the Answer If you decide that is Wrong please reopen this Question.+