# how to configure Code::Blocks for free form fortran

Tags: fortran, codeblocks

I have a fortran program and Code::Blocks IDE is complaining a line is truncated, so how do I specify this is free form fortran source code in Code::Blocks.

From the '**Build log**' tab, here is an excerpt of the warnings and failures:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in swat_cb (compiler: GNU Fortran Compiler)---------------

mingw32-gfortran.exe -Jobj\Debug\ -Wall  -g     -c C:\Users\TZ\f90apps\SWAT\src\biozone.f -o obj\Debug\src\biozone.o
Warning: Nonconforming tab character in column 1 of line 2
Warning: Nonconforming tab character in column 1 of line 126
Warning: Line truncated at (1)
C:\Users\Tong.Zhai\f90apps\SWAT\src\biozone.f:167.72:
        if(sep_tsincefail(j)>0) sep_tsincefail(j) = sep_tsincefail(j) + 
                                                                        1
Error: Syntax error in expression at (1)
```

line2 is an empty line, but has a 'tab' character at the beginning

line126 is as follows:

```
<tab>implicit none
```

line167 is as follows:

```
  if(sep_tsincefail(j)>0) sep_tsincefail(j) = sep_tsincefail(j) + 1
```

line167 is the first of many errors saying the line is truncated at just after the last plus sign (+), which is column 71

Comment: actually, the line in question ends on column 72, so that's what prompted me to seek out free form flag in CB

Comment: Please post the build log of the failing compile. You will find it in the **Build log** tab (not the **Build messages** tab),

Comment: @MikeKinghan, please see my updated post that includes relevant Build log entries

Comment: @francescalus, there are 310 program files that were developed by others in the community, i don't think changing those names is a good solution to this. I am really looking for a configuration solution to this as this is perhaps the most common setting to configure in any legit fortran IDE

Comment: Just use the `-ffree-form` flag https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Fortran-Dialect-Options.html

Comment: @VladimirF, this looks promising, how do I specify this flag inside CB?

Comment: I have no idea, look for compiler options.

Comment: @VladimirF, i've looked, couldn't find it, that's why I asked the original question

Comment: Maybe try to search on the internet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208733/how-to-add-compiler-flags-on-codeblocks (10 seconds to google)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @VladimirF's hint, I found the place for setting the free form flag in CB for Fortran programs, here is the menu options to get to it:

Project -> Build options... to bring up the 'Project build options' dialog.

From the 'Compiler Flags' tab, scroll down to the 'Fortran dialect' group, where you can check the following two options:

In free form an entire line is meaningful [-ffree-line-length-none]

The free form layout used by the source files [-ffree-form]

After checking these, I recompiled the project and those errors about line truncated are gone.