# Fortran error, use '-fcoarray=' to enable

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran-coarrays

I'm having some troubles with an awkward error in fortran, this is the code I need in order to get simulation of materials in solid state

```
  PROGRAM EUCLID
    PRINT *, 'A?'
    READ *, NA
    IF (NA.LE.0) THEN
      PRINT *, 'A must be a positive integer.'
      STOP
    END IF
    PRINT *, 'B?'
    READ *, NB
    IF (NB.LE.0) THEN
      PRINT *, 'B must be a positive integer.'
      STOP
    END IF
    PRINT *, 'The GCD of', NA, ' and', NB, ' is', NGCD(NA, NB), '.'
    STOP
  END

  FUNCTION NGCD(NA, NB)
    IA = NA
    IB = NB
1   IF (IB.NE.0) THEN
      ITEMP = IA
      IA = IB
      IB = MOD(ITEMP, IB)
      GOTO 1
    END IF
    NGCD = IA
    RETURN
  END
```

The error says Coarrays disabled at (1), use '-fcoarray=' to enable|, but I'm not using any arrays, so what should I do?

I'm using codeblocks as my compiler, and had no issues with some previous programs I wrote

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any coarray or are trying to wrongly declare an array with square brackets (like this: `integer :: arr[,]`) in any part of your code and included/linked files? Could you point us which line of code the error is referring to?

Comment: where is the subroutine `init_random_seed`?

Comment: Please provide more details about the underlying compiler used.  Also, perhaps you could try removing the `call init_random_seed` part.

Comment: Alternatively, of course, try adding an appropriate `-fcoarray=` flag to the compile options.  Again, we'll need details of your compiler to be able to suggest an appropriate value.

Comment: Consider changing `init_random_seed` to the intrinsic `random_seed` procedure.

Comment: this is the subrutine I'm using https://pastebin.com/DtX6nGvV

Comment: @francescalus how to add that flag to my codeblocks compiler?

Comment: See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33208733/3157076).

Comment: As the subroutine you link to is probably very relevant please copy it directly into your question.

Comment: fixed it by removing the init_random_seed, thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not planning to use coarrays and don't bother with threads and images, just abandon this custom `init_random_seed` subroutine and substitute it with the intrinsic `random_seed` subroutine. From the function reference [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html):

> If RANDOM_SEED is called without arguments, it is seeded with random
>   data retrieved from the operating system.

Else, if you do plan to use coarray features and do bother with threads and images (only recommended for advanced usage) you can use the new intrinsic `random_init`, if it is avaliable in your compiler. If it is not, then it is advisable to use a library, like [OpenCoarrays](https://sourceryinstitute.github.io/OpenCoarrays/proc/init_random_seed.html), or implement it by your own.

Comment: Please use the GFortran documentation matching the version of the compiler used. For that PRNG, in particular, there were large changes in gcc 7.

Answer (score 0):

init_random_seed I was using was implemented the wrong way, so I removed it completely and edited the code