# I get an error "a problem caused the program to stop working correctly.Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is found"

Tags: c, windows, runtime-error, codeblocks

I have a written a c program on the product of two matrices.When i compile i find no error but when i run it i find the aforementioned error.I have tried multiple solutions as suggested by youtube videos.But nothing worked.I have pirated windows 10 copy installed on my pc.I run the program on *codeblocks 20.03*
Here is the program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int r1,r2,c1,c2,a[r1][c1],b[r2][c2],c[r1][c2],sum=0;
    printf("Enter the rows and columns Of matrix a and b(r1,c1,r2,c2):");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d",&r1,&c1,&r2,&c2);
    printf("Input matrices elements");
    int i,j;
    printf("Input elements of matrix a:");
    for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c1;j++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("Input elements of matrix b:");
    for(i=0;i<r2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
        scanf("%d",b[i][j]);
    }
    printf("Matrix a is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c1;j++)
        printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("Matrix b is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<r2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
        printf("%d ",b[i][j]);
    }
    if(c1==r2)
    printf("\nMatrix multiplication is possible.....\n");
    else
    return 0;

    for(i=0;i<r2;i++){
        sum=0;
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
        sum+=a[i][j]*b[j][i];
        c[i][j]=sum;
    }
    printf("\nProduct of matrices is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
        printf("%d ",c[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** My program may not be correct,all i want to do is run the program and letter on i will debug it.

Comment: This can't be right: the variable arrays in the first line of `main()` have dimensions of `r1`, `c1` (etc) that are not initialized, so nobody knows how much memory is actually allocated.

Comment: Why don't you debug it *now*? Obviously you have a problem *now* so why would you say that you won't debug it until later?

Comment: Don't "fix" the code in your question, it invalidates large parts of the posted answers.

Comment: @user253751 a person can debug the problem only after he is able to execute it.In the present scenario program wouldn't execute after first two inputs.

Comment: @Blastfurnace thanks for your suggestion,next time i will keep this thing in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the primary problem in

```
  int r1,r2,c1,c2,a[r1][c1],b[r2][c2],c[r1][c2],sum=0;
```

where you use the values of `r1`, `r2`, `c1`, `c2` when they are indeterminate (i.e., not initialized or assigned).  You should see some compiler warnings along the lines of

```
warning: ‘r1’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
warning: ‘c2’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
warning: ‘r2’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

If you don't see them, use your compiler flags to enable warnings.

To solve this: You would need to scan the values first, and then use them as array dimensions.

Then, the next problem: you have a typo at

```
 scanf("%d",b[i][j]);
```

it should be

```
 scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
            ^^
```

That said, always check for the return value of `scanf()` to ensure scanning success before you use the scanned values.

Comment: Even after modifying code to `a[10][10],b[10][10],c[10][10]` it takes input of r1,c1,r2,c2 ,elements of matrices a and b, but still gives the same error

Comment: @Shubham Updated answer to address that.

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling with `clang -Weverything -Wno-vla`:

```
c.c:17:20: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%d",b[i][j]);
               ~~  ^~~~~~~
c.c:4:27: warning: variable 'c1' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    int r1,r2,c1,c2,a[r1][c1],b[r2][c2],c[r1][c2],sum=0;
                          ^~
c.c:4:17: note: initialize the variable 'c1' to silence this warning
    int r1,r2,c1,c2,a[r1][c1],b[r2][c2],c[r1][c2],sum=0;
                ^
                 = 0
c.c:4:23: warning: variable 'r1' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    int r1,r2,c1,c2,a[r1][c1],b[r2][c2],c[r1][c2],sum=0;
                      ^~
c.c:4:11: note: initialize the variable 'r1' to silence this warning
    int r1,r2,c1,c2,a[r1][c1],b[r2][c2],c[r1][c2],sum=0;
          ^
           = 0
c.c:4:37: warning: variable 'c2' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    int r1,r2,c1,c2,a[r1][c1],b[r2][c2],c[r1][c2],sum=0;
                                    ^~
c.c:4:20: note: initialize the variable 'c2' to silence this warning
    int r1,r2,c1,c2,a[r1][c1],b[r2][c2],c[r1][c2],sum=0;
                   ^
                    = 0
c.c:4:33: warning: variable 'r2' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    int r1,r2,c1,c2,a[r1][c1],b[r2][c2],c[r1][c2],sum=0;
                                ^~
c.c:4:14: note: initialize the variable 'r2' to silence this warning
    int r1,r2,c1,c2,a[r1][c1],b[r2][c2],c[r1][c2],sum=0;
             ^
              = 0
```

You initialize all your matrizes with a garbage value size, as you 1. didn't initialize the variables and 2. declared the VLAs on the same line==> Leading to garbage sizes.

First read the values from the user, then declare an VLA. (Although using `malloc` and Co. would be better).

Comment: @JCWasmax86 I don't know how to compile with clang -Weverything -Wno-vla .I am just started learning my first programming language.

Comment: How do you compile with an IDE or from the commandline?

Comment: Does this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40962079/13912132) help you? BUT: You can't use `-Weverything` with codeblocks. Use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, as gcc doesn't support `-Weverything`. If you additionally use `-Werror`, your compiler will make all warnings to errors.